# Code compiles in Eclipse but not with g++ on Linux

Tags: c++, g++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
struct process
{
    int burst;
    int ar;
};

vector<process> a;
// insert two processes
a.push_back({21, 42});
a.push_back({10, 20});
queue <process> names; 
names.push(a[1]); 
names.push(a[2]);
cout<<names.front().ar;
return 0; 
}
```

The above code is working fine in eclipse but when i compile it on linux it give  many errors. invalid argument and many more. i'm executing it with command:

```
g++ -o file_name file_name.cpp
```

does anyone know the reason behind these errors? any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the definition of `struct process` out of the main function:

```
struct process
{
    int burst;
    int ar;
};

int main ()
{
    ...
}
```

Additionally, since you use  initializer lists you must enable C++11 suport in GCC:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o file_name file_name.cpp
```

Comment: Thank$ for ur correction. All the errors are gone. But there is one still there 
   a.push_back({21,42});
 error is:
 expected primerey expression before token '}'

Comment: @RanaJunaidJaved which errors do you get exactly? add them to your question

Comment: when i executed command with -std=c++11 it says unrecognized command -std=C++11.

Comment: Then your GCC version is [too old](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html). You can try using `-std=c++0x` instead or use a newer version of GCC.

Comment: GCC 4.7 and above support c++11, check your version with g++ --version

Comment: @MateuszKacprzak can u help me to update GCC? cuz there is no option in GCC to update?

Comment: @RanaJunaidJaved update process strongly depends on your OS, so until I know your system I can do nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can not define a struct within a function. In your case, the struct process is defined within the main function.

Also, you need to declare the type of struct you wish to append to the vector.
the '{21, 42}' does not declare a 'process' type (Unless you use C++11).

Comment: thanks for ur reply. After moving struct out of main function there is still an error which is at  a.push_back({24,42}) and it says:
expected primary expression before '}' token.

Comment: @RanaJunaidJaved That expression requires C++11 support. You need to turn it on by passing `-std=c++11` on the command line.

Comment: @pmr i passed and executed command like this
  g++ -std=c++11 -o file file.cpp
  but it says 
   unrecognized command -std=c++11.?

Answer (score 0):

Using [local classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Local_classes) as template arguments and [passing braced-init-list to functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) are only possible as of C++11. Pass `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` option to g++ and all the errors will disappear. Note that all the letters in the option are in lower case.